# Get selected custom options value Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2, custom-options

I created an observer on `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` event, I want to get selected custom options values for this particular order. How can I do this please help? Please check the following code:

```
public function execute(Observer $observer) {

    $order_id = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds()[0];

    // \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
    $order = $this->_orderRepositoryInterface->get($order_id);

    $order_items = $order->getItems();

    foreach ($order_items as $order_item) {
        //Here I want to get selected custom options values for each item
        //With other fields like product name, price and other product related data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code:

```
<?php
/**
 * User: amit-pc
 * Date: 28/12/18
 */

namespace Stackexchange\Magento\Observer;


use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository;


class SuccessPage implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var OrderInterface
     */
    private $order;
    /**
     * @var OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $orderRepository;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\OptionFactory
     */
    private $optionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\OptionFactory $optionFactory
    )
    {

        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->optionFactory = $optionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {

        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();

        if(isset($orderIds[0]))
        {
            $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderIds[0]);
            $items = $order->getItems();

            foreach ($items as $item)
            {
                if ($options = $item->getProductOptions()) {
                    if (isset($options['options'])) {

                        foreach ($options['options'] as $_option){
                            // got option as index => option label and  value = option value
                            $optionsAssview = $this->getCustomOption($_option);
                        }
                    }
                }
                //$item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * get Option
     * @param $_option
     * @return array
     */
    private function getCustomOption($_option)
    {
        $result = [];
        $result['label'] = $_option['label'];
        if (isset($_option['custom_view']) && $_option['custom_view'])
        {
            $result['value'] =  $this->getCustomizedOptionValue($_option);
        }else{
            $result['value'] =$_option['value'];
        }
        return $result;
    }
    private function getCustomizedOptionValue($optionInfo)
    {
        // render customized option view
        $_default = $optionInfo['value'];
        if (isset($optionInfo['option_type'])) {
            try {
                $group = $this->optionFactory->create()->groupFactory($optionInfo['option_type']);
                return $group->getCustomizedView($optionInfo);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return $_default;
            }
        }
        return $_default;
    }

}
```

**NOte:$optionsAssview variable  has selected custom options values  and label**